# In XCUITest deeply nested elements have wrong accessibility features

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest

In my app I have a structure as follows:

```
-->Parents
---->TableView
------>TableViewCell (identifier: "MyTableViewCell")
-------->CollectionView
---------->CollectionViewCell
------------>Label
```

However, when I use `XCUIApplication().debugDescription` it gives me this:

```
-->Parents
---->TableView
------>TableViewCell
-------->StaticText (instead of collectionView.cell.label)
```

Thus when I have a query `XCUIApplication().cells["MyTableViewCell"].collectionViews` the test fails with unfound element.

So it seems like XCode is ignoring deeply nested XCUIElements and simply puts them all together on some other parent. However if I use the developer tools > accessibility inspector then I can see a proper structure. But in code it is not working and is presented differently.

How can I resolve this issue properly?

Comment: When you have complicated nesting inside your UI `XCUITest` can have certain problems. Try to set the `accessibilityIdentifier` for the element in code or in IB and is a better way to access your elements from `XCUITest`.

Comment: I have the identifiers set for all the elements that i Listed. However the problem is that I simply have no way of getting the collection view element. It is simply absent, although it has its own identifier.

Comment: I have the same issue but in another collection view cell, where there is a button in it. The button is not even being shown in the debug description, instead of it I have a staticText on a table view cell with the button title, but no button element itself. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
It helped me to use accessibilityElements in TableViewCell (I found the advice here [Custom UITableViewCell accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459458/custom-uitableviewcell-accessibility))

Try to set in your TableViewCell

```
accessibilityElements = [CollectionView]
```