# Accessibility voice over issue in UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a screen which has one `UITableView`. The tableview has two sections with the same type of cells. When i check the accessibility through the accessibility inspector, it does not go through all the cells at the bottom, rather it reads some cells and then jumps back to top itself. The `UITableViewCell` has 2 `UILabel` and one `UIButton`. I have set the accessibilityElements as below:

```
self.accessibilityElements = [label1, label2, button].compactMap{$0}
```

Note: If i donot set the `accessibilityElements`, then the accessibility reads all the cells on the screen upto the end, but the order of the elements in each `UITableViewCell` is not correct due to which i have to set the `accessibilityElements` here.
Does anybody has any idea of this behaviour and how can it be fixed?

Comment: How you taken a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459458/custom-uitableviewcell-accessibility

Comment: @JMIT, yes i have checked that and i am setting the accessibilityElements the same way but its not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: my cell has many subviews and they were out of order through the voiceOver. So I tried to do the same as you, adding the  subviews into the `accessibilityElements`. But it caused me to get stuck on the first cells, just like yourself. So I did this in my `UITableViewCell` class and it worked:

```
override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        super.didAddSubview(subview)
        accessibilityElements = subview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case. On my screen, I have a static tableView, with static cells. See the screenshot. But the issue was when using **Accessibility Inspector**, it could only read the whole cell and whole static string `Connection WiFi` instead of two different texts.

From the mentioned link, I found the solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58183764/3231194

Since I couldn't subclass the cell and it seems unideal to do so (I am using Storyboard), I just had to make IBOutlets, and continue everything from there.

```
  self.connectionTitleLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = @"sync-settings-connection-title";
  self.connectionType.accessibilityIdentifier = @"sync-settings-connection-type";
  self.connectionCell.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
  self.connectionCell.accessibilityElements = @[self.connectionTitleLabel, self.connectionType];
```

[image]